# MYSQL Change Enum Values

Tags: mysql, laravel, mysql-error-1064

In my table named "stocktakings", there is a column from type ENUM called "status". "status" has the following fields:

- 'Pending'
- 'Processing'
- 'Failed'
- 'Succeeded'

I want to change the values to:

- 'ready for relocation'
- 'search shelf location'
- 'stock update succeeded'
- 'stock update failed'
- 'updating stock'

I tried the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE `stocktakings` MODIFY `stocktakings.status` 
    `stocktakings.status` ENUM(
        `ready_for_relocation`,
        `search_shelf_location`,
        `stock_update_succeeded`,
        `stock_update_failed`,
        `updating_stock`
);
```

Didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Migration - Update Enum Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251186/laravel-migration-update-enum-options)

Comment: You are going from 4 enum values to 5 enum values. How do they map ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You cannot just remove the Old Enum values from the Column definition. Otherwise, there will be an irreparable Data loss (all fields may turn to blank). It will be a multi-step process:

Add new Enum Values to Existing Column definition. Also, Enum values are surrounded by single quotes (not backticks)

```
ALTER TABLE `stocktakings` MODIFY `stocktakings`.`status` ENUM(
        'Pending', 
        'Processing', 
        'Failed', 
        'Succeeded', 
        'ready_for_relocation',
        'search_shelf_location',
        'stock_update_succeeded',
        'stock_update_failed',
        'updating_stock'
);
```

Now, run an `Update` query to Update all the enum values correspondingly:

```
UPDATE `stocktakings` 
SET status = CASE status 
               WHEN 'Pending' THEN 'ready_for_relocation'
               WHEN 'Processing' THEN 'search_shelf_location'
               WHEN 'Failed' THEN 'stock_update_failed'
               WHEN 'Succeeded' THEN 'stock_update_succeeded'
             END
```

Now, `Alter Table` and remove the Old enum values.

```
ALTER TABLE `stocktakings` MODIFY `stocktakings`.`status` ENUM(
            'ready_for_relocation',
            'search_shelf_location',
            'stock_update_succeeded',
            'stock_update_failed',
            'updating_stock'
    );
```