# alter enum default option values in existing migration laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I have created a migration and added a new column expiry with the enum type.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('admin_assignform', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->enum('expiry',['0','Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly','Quarterly','Yearly'])->comment('0:never')->after('formname')->default(0);
    });
}
```

and

```
run php artisan migrate
```

After that, I realize I can one more option in enum

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('admin_assignform', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->enum('expiry',['0','Daily', 'Weekly', 'Monthly','Quarterly','Yearly', 'Cycle'])->comment('0:never')->after('formname')->default(0);
    });
}
```

How can I add the `'Cycle'` option in the enum default value?

Comment: What database system are you using? Not every DBMS supports changes like this (if any for this particular case).

Comment: I am using MYSQL

Comment: I found this solution but I am unable to use it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25251270/3041435

Comment: Why are you unable to use it? [According to the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#modifying-columns), you cannot change `enum` columns (see the red warning box).