# How to change enum value and also add new column in laravel migration simultaneously

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I want to change enum value and also need to add new column in laravel migration. How can I excute this at a time!

Initially, I have 2 enum in my status column SEARCHED,DOWNLOADED, I want to DOWNLOAD_FAILED and want to add new column as remark

Schema::table('user_ckyc', function (Blueprint $table) {
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE user_ckyc CHANGE COLUMN status status ENUM('SEARCHED', 'DOWNLOADED' 'DOWNLOAD_FAILED') DEFAULT PENDING");
$table->string('remark', 50)->nullable();
});

Comment: Possible solution is already on sof [Laravel Migration - Update Enums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25251186/laravel-migration-update-enum-options?rq=2)